# Horizontal auto swiping text

Tags: android, textview, sliding

How do I create an auto swiping text in android?  Something like those image slider in website but this is only text.

One text at a time and with sliding animation.  Anyone have any idea, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). ViewFlipper is introduced just for this purpose. Here is an example for the same [ViewFlipper Example.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Another optinal, you can use this library [Android Image Slider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) with custom [SliderAdapter](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/daimajia/slider/library/SliderAdapter.java) to using TextView instead of ImageView